# Можно ли создать ос без ассемблера и с?

Tags: ос

Мне стало интересно: можно ли создать свою ос без ассемблера и с?
Ведь в с я шарю не лучше чем в ракетостроении, а ассемблер для меня темный лес.
Можете сказать возможно ли это(либо дать статьи на эту тему) или нет.

Comment: Смотря где будет крутиться эта ОС. Если где-нибудь в веб-браузере, то можете хоть на JavaScript сделать )  А если надо на железе, как обычные ОС, то без ассемблера никак.

Comment: спасибо  большое

Comment: можно и без ассемблера, но это будет еще сложнее и дольше. )

Comment: А на чем кроме ассемблера?

Comment: @the_max_new, на любом компилируемом языке. Теоретически вы можете создавать бинарный код функций, содержещих необходимые машинные инструкции на любом языке, вставлять их при сборке в бинарный образ ОС и вызывать. Но все же проще написать их руками на ассемблере

Comment: спасибо большое!